# Refresh attribute table after SQL trigger

Tags: qgis, python, sql, spatialite, trigger

I'm utilizing a trigger on a SpatialLite layer in QGIS.

This trigger is designed to update a field when its content matches with another in the database.

Here's the trigger's code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_corine1
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_1 ON HABITAT_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITAT_POLY
    SET CORINE_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM BDD_Extract WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = EUNIS_1;)
    WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1;
END;
```

This code executes when the layer is saved. However, if the attribute table is open, the changes are not immediately visible. It requires closing and reopening the attribute table.

Is there a way to refresh the attribute table automatically? I've attempted using Python scripts, but they haven't behaved as desired. Ideally, the "refresh function" should execute when the attribute table is open, and this functionality should work consistently across all machines.

Is there a way to refresh the attribute table ? I have tried with python scripts, but it is not working the way I want. The "refresh function" should be executed when the attribute table is open, and it has to work on every machine.